# NetLogo - What is 1 distance unit in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo, traffic-simulation

I am working on traffic simulations using NetLogo for a post graduate project.

For turtles to move forward we can specify the number of units it can move e.g. `fd 1`, which would mean the turtle moves forward by 1. What is this 1 unit? Is it equal to 1 patch or equal to the size of the turtle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each step is the same size as the patches.

Answer (score 1):

As Luis said, each step is the size of one patch, but remember that steps are not restricted to integers, eg. fd 0.7 is a valid command and will move a turtle forward seven tenths of the size of a patch.

Answer (score 0):

The patches represent a roadway (if you're discussing a traffic simulation model) and one scales patches in a model appropriately, e.g. 1 patch=25 m....etc.!